# ¿Cómo puedo establecer la regla required como función desde la etiqueta html con jqueryValidate?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-validate

Estoy empleando la libreria JqueryValidate y por lo que he estado leyendo puedo crear una regla para determinado campo donde este sera requerido o no dependiendo de un criterio, por ejemplo si selecciono un checkbox anteriormente. El tema es que hacerlo en javascript es una boberia pero por varias razones me veo obligado a tratar de hacerlo a traves de html solamente. He usado el atributo data-rule- para asignarle determinadas restricciones a los campos por ejemplo

```
<input type="text" data-rule-minlength="2" />
```

Ahora lo que quisiera es hacerlo pero con el required
En javascript seria algo como esto

```
rules:{
  campo1: {
    required: function(){
      return $('#check1').prop('checked');
    }
  }
}
```

Cualquier ayuda sera mas que bienvenida.

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres decir es que no puedes usar los filtros de que dispones con jQuery Validate y que tienes que hacerlo por HTML? Si es así, entonces ¿cuál es el sentido de usar jQuery Validate?

Comment: A ver el problema es que tengo un jquery validate genérico que lo tengo en un script y lo cargo en todas las paginas donde necesite validar un form, y haciendo uso de html puedo agregar las reglas pero solo me haria falta como hacerlo con la regla required aceptando una función.